# Why is the Text not hiding while off page?

Tags: html, css, transition

For some reason I can't get the Text to hide while it transitions off the screen.
Example, I have a rectangle hidden off screen, but even after the page should end (sides of the page) the rectangle is still visible which is very odd. I've solved this issue before but I forgot.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
        <title>RNS|Blog</title>
</header>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<style>

#tuti {
margin-left: 1000px;
margin-right: 0;
}

    #tuti:hover {
width: 600px;
padding: 0px;
}

#tuti a {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 45px;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#tuti {
width: 30px;
height: 75px;
background-color: #655655;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;
opacity: 0.5;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
color: white;
font-weight: 300;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.right {
float: right;
}
}





</style>
    <h1 class="right", id="tuti"><a>really nice server I blog</a></h1>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eobwtvxL/

Comment: Your HTML is so invalid, internet explorer 6 renders it correctly. Please fixup your html and rephrase your question, I dont get what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that the text within the `a` tag has width and the `h1` tag should be set to `overflow:hidden`. Also, setting `position:absolute` on the `h1` will take it out of document flow and allow you to place it anywhere without affecting adjacent elements. Here is the cleaned up CSS:

```
#tuti {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    right:30px;
    top:30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #655655;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#tuti:hover {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#tuti a {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 45px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Cleaned up fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/eobwtvxL/1/

You also need to fix this:

```
<h1 class="right", id="tuti">
```

No comma:

```
<h1 class="right" id="tuti">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to assign `overflow:hidden;` to any element that contains the pullout bar. In your jsfiddle add this `#tuti {overflow:hidden;}` and you will see it will work.